# Is Ubuntu vulnerable to a Grub2 authentication bug?

Tags: grub2, security

Does this security bug affect Ubuntu?
It involves pressing backspace 28 times to break into a machine.

From [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/you-can-break-into-a-linux-system-by-pressing-backspace-1748370796):

> The researchers, Hector Marco and Ismael Ripoll from the Cybersecurity
>   Group at Polytechnic University of Valencia, found that it’s possible
>   to bypass all security of a locked-down Linux machine by exploiting a
>   bug in the Grub2 bootloader. Essentially, hitting backspace 28 times
>   when the machine asks for your username accesses the “Grub rescue
>   shell,” and once there, you can access the computer’s data or install
>   malware.

Comment: I agree with the first comment in that thread : "But realistically, if someone has physical access to your machine and has access to the boot process" . I would not rely on a grub password to protect much of anything.

Comment: Well, the article explicitly states Ubuntu has issued a patch....  Does that give us a clue?

Comment: For more context see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250028/ .

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in Ubuntu, reference: [Security Notice USN-2836-1](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2015-December/003218.html)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that this will only affect people who use a GRUB password prompt, which is not the default on Ubuntu.

So a default Ubuntu installation was never vulnerable.

If you do use a GRUB password prompt (which is arguably not a very strong protection anyway, since a person who sees the grub screens has physical access to the machine) then you are protected if you've installed all recent security updates - in particular, if your grub2-common package is one of the following versions or later:

```
Ubuntu 15.10:
  grub2-common                    2.02~beta2-29ubuntu0.2

Ubuntu 15.04:
  grub2-common                    2.02~beta2-22ubuntu1.4

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:
  grub2-common                    2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.6

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:
  grub2-common                    1.99-21ubuntu3.19
```

Comment: It's also not the default on any OS I know of.  It would be a very rare custom setup.  I call this a Lifehacker beat-up.  Article claims you can break into "most" Linux systems this way.

Comment: If we use a very liberal interpretation of "pressing backspace 28 times" to mean "press down, enter, press down until root, enter", sure, we can break into most Linux systems. :D